# Best design of member controller using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeignter and I am looking for input on the design of my members/users control panel.

I currently have my route as

```
$route['member/(.+)'] = "member/index/$1";
```

And my member controller as

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Member extends MY_Controller {

public $userid = '';

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->userid = $this->uri->segment(2);
}

function index()
{
    $this->display();   
}
```

The user ID should always be URI segment 2 or else I redirect to 404. The default page in the control panel is the profile page. I have 3 different areas in the control panel which are profile, settings and privacy. Users can display and edit data in these areas.

I have methods for display_profile, edit_profile, display_settings, edit_settings, etc. I am not sure if I should always evaluate the URL in my index or constructor and then call the correct method or some other design. Any input is appreciated.

The way it is currently designed, the user can be on a page, profile for example and click the settings link and the URL is member/1234/settings. Then if they click the edit button on the settings page, the URL is member/1234/settings/edit and the method edit_settings is called. Is this a good design?

Comment: Are there are any security issues with exposing the user id in the URL like that?

Comment: I don't think, I have security in place but I thought about taking it out all together. However there are many sites that display the user areas with the ID in the URL.